# FNSubscribe replacement in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I am unable to find a replacement for "FNSubscribe" method in CarbonCore framework. This function was used to watch a directory for any changes and execute a callback function in case of a change.

```
/*
*  FNSubscribe()
*  
*  Summary:
*    Subscribe to change notifications for the specified directory.
*  
*  Mac OS X threading:
*    Thread safe since version 10.1
*  
*  Parameters:
*    
*    directoryRef:
*      Directory for which the caller wants notifications
*    
*    callback:
*      Function to call back when a notification arrives
*    
*    refcon:
*      User state carried with the subscription
*    
*    flags:
*      Options for future use (specify kNilOptions, or one of the
*      FNSubscriptionOptions)
*    
*    subscription:
*      Subscription token for subsequent query or unsubscription
*  
*  Availability:
*    Mac OS X:         in version 10.1 and later in CoreServices.framework
*    CarbonLib:        not available in CarbonLib 1.x, is available on Mac OS X version 10.1 and later
*    Non-Carbon CFM:   not available
*/
extern OSStatus  FNSubscribe(const FSRef *directoryRef, FNSubscriptionUPP callback, void *refcon, OptionBits flags, FNSubscriptionRef *subscription) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_1, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
```

How can I watch a directory using Cocoa and eventually run a callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with OS X 10.5 you can use the [File System Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (aka FSEvents) API.